# Reading a value from raw memory (MISRA compliant)

Tags: c++, casting, misra

I'm trying to read the value of a variable previously write on NVM flash.

My code is:

```
uintptr_t address = getAddress();
//[MISRA C++ Rule 5-2-8] cast from unsigned int to pointer
uint16_t value = *(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(address));
```

The problem is the cast from uintptr_t to pointer is not allowed in MISRA. Do anyone knows a way to access this memory?

I'm breaking one of the big rules of MISRA. Using dynamic memory (the contents of flash is dynamic so the address of data is variable). Only cause if you're thinking of declare a const pointer to the flash address and access it after the data is write.

What are the rules for if not for break them? :)

Comment: "Dynamic memory"  should not be a MISRA problem. If `GetAddress` returned a `void*`, a `static_cast` would be sufficient and your tool probably would not complain.

Comment: GetAddres can't return a pointer cause the address is stored on an integer variable. So if getAddres does: void * ptr= reinterpret_cast[void*](address);  the problem will be the same but in other place. (I used [] cause I'm in the phone and don't have gt and lt symbols)

Comment: Then fix that - store it in a `void*` as well. The real problem is still the same: you are using the wrong type for an address. MISRA is fairly strict in that regard, store pointers in pointer variables.

Comment: At runtime:
Device allocate space to accommodate the table in flash.
Store the start address also in flash.
The table is also write to flash.
The problem is address this table. I only have the position in flash (uint32_t).
Imagine a table of 300 uint16_t. How to access item[10]?
For performance I need to directly address flash memory.
See my "solution"

Comment: You really should provide a lot more details. What is that "position in flash" ? If I imagine a table of 300 uint16_t, I imagine `uint16_t item[300]` and the compiler is then perfectly capable of calculating `item[10]` for me. Now it may be that I only know `uint16_t* item;` but even then the compiler calculates `item[10]` for me. You can get from one pointer to another by adding a constant, but it all begins with an address.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it. I only have 2 "solutions" to the problem:

1.- Don't be MISRA compliant.

2.- Use static addresses on a dynamic environment:

At compile time:

```
const Table1 table1 __attribute__ ((section (".table1space")));
const Table2 table2 __attribute__ ((section (".table2space")));
```

Define the required sections on linker script.

At runtime:

When dynamic allocation is called for table1. Static table1 address is returned and so on.

Answer (score 1):

MISRA C++ (Required) Rule 5-2-8 is attempting to stop you doing things, which lead to *unspecified behaviour*.  The equivalent MISRA C:2012 guideline is (Advisory) Rule 11.4

And in general converting an integer to a pointer is undesirable, as there are a variety of possible problems, not least to do with alignment.

The MISRA C guideline has some extra narrative

> Casting between a pointer and an integer type should be avoided where possible, but may be necessary when addressing memory mapped registers or other hardware specific features.

The ***correct*** method for dealing with this is to raise a deviation. This documents the reason ***why*** you need to do it, but also makes you ***consider*** the consequences, and to ***show*** that you are mitigating them.

Comment: What unspecified behavior? C++03 5.2.10 Reinterpret cast §5 explicitly states "A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer. A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type
will have its original value; mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined."  In addition, the MISRA (C or C++) rule was always hogwash - you must be able to convert from integers to pointers by cast, or MISRA can't be used for embedded systems - MCU register maps.

Comment: As for misaligned access or conversion to non-compatible pointer type, or lvalue access through a pointer with wrong type - these are 3 cases of _undefined behavior_.

Comment: In MISRA C we reclassified the Rule to Advisory... in fact we wanted to disapply it for hardware access and leave it required for other, but that is not decidable, so leaving it to the user to annotate accordingly is better.

Comment: The rule should removed altogether. You cannot write the kind of programs MISRA-C was intended for without breaking it. Register access, implementing interrupt vector tables, writing NVM programming drivers, accessing unnamed memory (DMA etc) are all cases of every day embedded systems programming. Having some whiny rule which 100% of the applications must deviate from isn't helping anyone, it just makes people hostile to MISRA-C. A better rule would focus on the actual problems: misalignment, pointer type compatibility and strict aliasing. Rather than blindly banning every conversion.

Comment: Anyway, my initial comment was that none of this is _unspecified_ behavior, which is a formal term in C and C++. Not to be confused with undefined and impl.defined. I'm sure you know this though.

Comment: The Rule has its place - it should apply in all situations where you are not accessing hardware.  But adding that level of granularity requires some fundamental work on the Rules...

Answer (score 0):

If `getAddress()` returns an integral type which is actually supposed to be used like a pointer, let's assume it's 2-byte aligned since your datum is `uint16_t`:

```
uintptr_t offset = getAddress();
assert(offset % sizeof(uint16_t) == 0);
uint16_t* address = 0;
address += offset / sizeof(uint16_t);
uint16_t value = *address;
```

Comment: GetAddress is a mock function. It only illustrates the problem. In this case the platform requires all pointers shall be 16 bits aligned. That's not the problem.

In your code you're doing pointer arithmetic (address + = offset...) that is also prohibited by MISRA rules.

I'm asking if there is a way to access non static defined memory without losing MISRA compliance.

Comment: You know MISRA better than I do.  It sort of sounds like MISRA intends to prevent doing what you are trying to do.  Perhaps there is simply a mismatch here--wrong horse or wrong course.

Comment: Yes. You're right. I think it's not possible to use ant kind of dynamic memory in MISRA environment even if it is totally controlled. Every pointer shall be placed and sized at compile time. TT. Well I'll keep trying.

Comment: If you're allowed to read disk files, perhaps you could write a simple kernel module to expose the value you want as an always-readable file.  Like procfs does.  Or maybe do the same with FUSE if you're on Linux.

Comment: @IvanPajuelo: `malloc` returns memory which isn't sized at compile time, and it can return a `void*`. That proves the cast problem is **not** caused by "dynamic memory" per se, merely by your implementation thereof.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @IvanPajuelo's answer (my proposed edit seems to have been rejected) - there are in fact THREE options, not just the two specified by @IvanPajuelo:

1. Don't be MISRA compliant
2. Fudge things to "shut up the checker"
3. Deviate

The Guidelines document explains the mechanism for dis-applying a rule via a Deviation, and this is one of those situations that a Deviation is certainly valid.

So much so, that work is ongoing on documenting some standard Approved Deviations - of which this is one of them (classification R6 in this document)!!

http://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=1253
http://www.misra.org.uk/forum/download/file.php?id=627

(You may need to be Logged In to the Bulletin Board to access the download)